# synchronize tfs or project work items with outlook tasks

Tags: tfs, outlook, task, ms-project

Is it possible to synchronize tfs (2008 or 2010) or project 2010 work items with outlook tasks  (without the project server)? Is it possible to send a work item from tfs or project 2010 as an outlook task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

**Option 1: Server side**

- You can connect a Sharepoint Tasks list with Outlook

You get the items into Sharepoint by:

- I am sure project has some pretty good Sharepoint integration (not 100% but I think it does)
- You can use the TFS Integration Platfrom to do a two way sync from TFS to Sharepoint
  http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

**Option 2: Client side only (no server)**

So the best option in this regard is to use a tool that makes it look like your work items are inside Outlook and give you the same facilities as tasks. Remember Work Items have a lot more fields and statuses than Tasks so you can't do a direct link without loosing information.

I would recommend using [Team Companion](http://www.ekobit.com/ProductsDetailView.aspx?id=1) which I think is your best solution.

Comment: As I wrote above "without the project server". TFS 2010 doesn't need no to be installed the SharePoint, so I don't have SharePoint. 
I'm looking for solution that synchronizes Outlook Tasks for a team member either from TFS (without SharePoint) or from the Project client directly.

Comment: watch out, sync is not longer supported by tfs itself for tfs 2016+, see: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs15-relnotes#project-server-integration-no-longer-supported